# How to calculate slope in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

If I have an array of 50 elements,  how would I calculate a 3 period slope and a 5 period slope? 
The docs dont add much.....

```
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.random.random(10)
>>> y = np.random.random(10)
>>> slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
```

Would this work?

```
def slope(x, n): 
   if i<len(x)-n: 
        slope = stats.linregress(x[i:i+n],y[i:i+n])[0]
        return slope
```

but the would the arrays be the same length

@joe:::

```
xx = [2.0 ,4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30]
x  = np.asarray(xx, np.float)
s  = np.diff(x[::3])/3

window  = [1, 0, 0, 0,  -1]
window2 = [1, 0,  -1]
slope   = np.convolve(x, window, mode='same') / (len(window) - 1)
slope2  = np.convolve(x, window2, mode='same') / (len(window2) - 1)

print x
print s

print slope
print slope2
```

Results.....

```
[  2.   4.   6.   8.  10.  12.  14.  16.  18.  20.  22.  24.  26.  28.  30.]
[ 2.  2.  2.  2.]
[ 1.5  2.   2.   2.   2.   2.   2.   2.   2.   2.   2.   2.   2.  -6.  -6.5]
[  2.   2.   2.   2.   2.   2.   2.   2.   2.   2.   2.   2.   2.   2. -14.]
```

The slope and slope2 are what Im after except the  -6, -6.5 and -14 arent the results I am  looking for.

this worked.......

```
window    = [1, 0, 0, -1]
slope     = np.convolve(xx, window, mode='valid') / float(len(window) - 1)
padlength = len(window) -1
slope     = np.hstack([np.ones(padlength), slope])
print slope
```

Comment: Running linear regression on the entire set of 50 observations would give you a slope and an intercept. Could you explain what exactly you mean by an "**N-period** slope"?

Comment: if series 1,2 ...........50, I would like slope of 46,47,48,49,50, and slope of 48,49,50. As a array. so all elements have corresponding slopes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the slope calculated on every 3rd and 5th element so that you have a series of (exact, not least-squares) slopes?

If so, you'd just do something along the lines of:

```
third_period_slope = np.diff(y[::3]) / np.diff(x[::3])
fifth_period_slope = np.diff(y[::5]) / np.diff(x[::5])
```

I'm probably entirely misunderstanding what you mean, though.  I've never head the term "3 period slope" before...

If you want more of a "moving window" calculation (so that you have the same number of input elements as output elements), just model it as a convolution with a window of `[-1, 0, 1]` or `[-1, 0, 0, 0, 1]`.

E.g.

```
window = [-1, 0, 1]
slope = np.convolve(y, window, mode='same') / np.convolve(x, window, mode='same')
```

Comment: I dont understend 'convolve' , get 'con' fused

Comment: Read up a bit on convolutions, you'll thank yourself for doing it later on. They're rather ubiquitous! :) The difference between the convolution and @tom's answer above is that the convolution will use _only_ the 1st and 3rd points, then only the 2nd and 4th points, etc, rather than using the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd, then 2nd, 3rd, and 4th points, etc.  As I said earlier, I'm assuming that you _didn't_ want a linear regression, but rather an exact fit. (The linear regression will be a couple orders of magnitude slower, but if you don't have a ton of points, it won't matter much.)

Comment: what if y is not defined, there is only a array of x?

Comment: In that case, you can just divide by the step size.  e.g. `slope = np.convolve(x, window, mode='same') / (len(window) - 1)`

Comment: You need to decide what you want to do at the boundaries. By default, things are padded with 0.  Use `mode='valid'` instead of `mode='same'` if you want to avoid the boundaries entirely.

Comment: Using 'valid', how would I get the array length to match? As 'same' does, I would like to add 1 or 0 to beginning to array.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3282/discussion-between-joe-kington-and-merlin)

Answer (score 3):

Just use the subset of the data that contains the points (periods -- I'm assuming you're talking about financial data here) you're interested in:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    if i<len(x)-3:
        slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x[i:i+3],y[i:i+3])
    if i<len(x)-5:
        slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x[i:i+5],y[i:i+5])
```

(This isn't the most efficient approach, btw, if all you want is the slopes, but it's easy.)

Comment: I was thinking some like slope(x,3) or slope (x,5) where return was only the slope vector or array .....

Comment: That's the basic idea, except in your def, what's i?, in mine it's the loop variable, so each i gives the slope of a different set of points; and also, linregress will return a tuple, not a single value, so you can either assign them all to variables, or just assign the tuple and pick off the first entry, like r = stats.linregress(x[i:i+n], y[i:i+n]), then slope = r[0], or just slope = (stats.linregress(x[i:i+n],y[i:i+n]))[0].

Comment: can you fix answer above with comment solution.